# How to quickly jump into next tag in sublime text3?

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I often need to create long list with many `<li>`s using *Emmet* in Sublime. After creating the empty `<li>` tag pairs, I need to put text content between each tag. This is when I need to jump between the `<li>` tag pairs frequently to edit the content.

Is there a shortcut key for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the nested `<li>` tags (perhaps by using `ul>li*5` or something similar), as long as you don't click anywhere else, you can hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to skip from `<li></li>` pair to pair, with the cursor landing between the opening and closing tags. You can then type the content you wish, and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to the next pair.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I just found out why I didn't try this out: I was trying to edit contents, not adding to empty list items. Once there is content, the Tab can't be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Wont get much closer than this

“Next Edit Point” (⌃⌥→)